# React Navigation with transitionConfig

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

While using

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen1');
```

transitionConfig is working fine, animating properly. But while

```
this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.reset(
    {
     index: 0,
     actions: [
      NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home'})
     ]
    }));
```

transitionConfig animation is not working. **How can I show transition while dispatch ?**